# Using Python and Tweepy - How to reply with set text each time a specific user tweets?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am able to reply to a specific tweet by getting tweet IDs, but cannot get my configuration to do what I want it to do, which is to reply to every tweet from a specific user. I have that user's username and ID. Currently it appears to only be pulling one tweet, which I suspect has something to do with line 23's `tweet.id`. I guess what I'm looking for is a way to ensure that my bot replies every single time this user tweets.  Here is my current code (sensitive info redacted)

```
from ast import For
import tweepy

api_key = "###############################################"
api_secret = "###############################################"
bearer_token = r"###############################################"
access_token = "###############################################"
access_token_secret = "###############################################"

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token, api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)

auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(api_key, api_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

toReply = "TwitterUsernameHere"
api = tweepy.API(auth)

tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = toReply, count=1)

for tweet in tweets:
    api.update_status("@" + toReply + " Why? ", in_reply_to_status_id = tweet.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are following the [Twitter automation rules](https://help.twitter.com/en/rules-and-policies/twitter-automation) (i.e. that you're only replying to Tweets that the user has opted-in for your app to reply to - otherwise your user account or app will be restricted)...

... your code currently checks the user's Timeline, and then replies to the most recent single Tweet (`count=1` on the `user_timeline` call). You would need this to check for *new* Tweets in order to reply to different ones. You could store `tweet.id` somewhere and only reply to it when it changes.

Note that there are a few other things to tidy up:

- `from ast import For` is not required
- `client = tweepy.Client` targets the Twitter API v2 but the rest of the code uses Twitter API v1.1 (via `tweepy.API`)
- `bearer_token` is unused in this code and will only work for a read operation in v1.1 of the API so you could remove it.